# How to set the width of images loaded with ajax?

Tags: jquery

I'm having a pictures website and have implemented infinite scrolling of pictures.
The problem is that I don't know how to resize the images with jQuery after they are loaded.

And I'm using drupal with jQuery version 1.5.

This is my code so far that does not work:

```
jQuery(body).delegate("#region-content","onchange",function() {
jQuery('#region-content img').each(function() {
    var desiredWidth = 520; // Max width for the image
    var ratio = 0;  // Used for aspect ratio
    var width = jQuery(this).width();    // Current image width
    var height = jQuery(this).height();  // Current image height



    if(width != desiredWidth){
        ratio = desiredWidth / width;   // get ratio for scaling image
        jQuery(this).css("width", desiredWidth); // Set new width
        jQuery(this).css("height", height * ratio);  // Scale height based on ratio
        height = height * ratio;    // Reset height to match scaled image
        width = width * ratio;    // Reset width to match scaled image
    }

});
});
```

Comment: Make sure the image is actually loaded so jQuery can see the width and height by using `.ready()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To maintain aspect, set only the width. And you can do in css:

**css**

```
#region-content{
  height: 520px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#region-content img{
  max-width: 520px; /* only width */
}
```

Comment: You can safely use max-width and max-height together without losing the aspect ratio.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I lost my mind and forget that it could be done through simple css.